# Auto-accept confirmation dialog on windows when pairing devices via WiFi Direct?

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, wifi-direct

Using WiFi direct sample at: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/WiFiDirect

Doesn't matter which pairing mode I use i.e. PushButton, Pin, Password. Eventually, windows built-in prompt pops-up asking whether to continue with pairing. Is it possible to auto-accept that prompt from within the application? It would be really useful when working with headless devices.

[image]

Comment: You should use DeviceInformationCustomPairing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformationcustompairing?view=winrt-22621

Comment: The linked sample I'm using is actually using DeviceInformationCustomPairing: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/main/Samples/WiFiDirect/cs/ConnectionSettingsPanel.xaml.cs

Comment: Actually if the CustomPairing is used and all the events are handled correctly there is no any system conformation dialog. At least we have never seen such one in our WiFi Framework. Probably something in that demo shows the dialog.

Comment: Is it possible you can review the sample code - especially the link I shared above and see what could be causing OS to display the prompt?

Comment: I do not use UWP in my work anyhow and have no any UWP SDK installed for any of my development tools. This is, probaly, UWP restriction that it shows such dialogs.

Comment: are you using same underlying APIs though? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.wifidirect?view=winrt-22621

Comment: More or less - yes.